# adding scores in current game to long term stats in Android

Tags: java, android

I am looking for some advice on keeping long term scores for Players in a game.

When I load the game it automatically creates 3 new `Player` objects with the names `Danny`, `Mark`, `Steve` (eventually I will sort these out properly so they are in a `List<Player>`

When I start a new game I choose the two player names from two `Spinner` the app then checks if the names in the selected Spinner match the name of any of the names of the `Player` objects.

This is my code for the main_menu where the players are selected from two Spinners

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Menu.this, MainActivity.class);
String p1Name = playerOnesName = p1Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String p2Name = playerTwosName = p2Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
intent.putExtra("message_key", playerOnesName);
intent.putExtra("message_key2", playerTwosName);
startActivity(intent);
```

I then check in main activity when I click start game, if the name of playerOnesName matches any of the names saved in the list of Players.

```java
p1Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("message_key");
p2Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("message_key2");

if (p1Name.equals(p3.getName())) {
  p1.setTotalDarts(p3TotalDarts);
  p1.setTotalScore(p3TotalScore);
  p1.setHighout(p3HighOut);
  if ((p1.getTotalScore()) != 0 || p1.getTotalDarts() != 0) {
    p1.setAverage(p1.getTotalScore() / p1.getTotalDarts());
  } else {
    p1.setAverage(0.0f);
  }
}
```

The code used to save the attributes,

```
public void save() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        editor.putInt("p4TotalScore", p4.getTotalScore());
        editor.putInt("p5TotalScore", p5.getTotalScore());
        editor.putInt("p3TotalScore", p3.getTotalScore());

        editor.putInt("p4TotalDarts", p4.getTotalDarts());
        editor.putInt("p5TotalDarts", p5.getTotalDarts());
        editor.putInt("p3TotalDarts", p3.getTotalDarts());

        editor.putInt("p4HighOut", p4.getHighout());
        editor.putInt("p5HighOut", p5.getHighout());
        editor.putInt("p3HighOut", p3.getHighout());
        //OVERALL_HIGH_OUT is a class variable.
        editor.putInt("highOut", OVERALL_HIGH_OUT);
        editor.apply();


    }
```

I have the same for all scenarios eg, p1 = p3, p4 or p5 and p2 = p3, p4 or p5.

I have a load button which loads the data for the shared prefs which holds the int values for p3,4,5 totalDarts, totalScore and hightOut.

I now want the app to loads the long term values for the above for the relevant player. such as if p1 represents p3, then p1 will get the `highOut` `totalScore` and `totalDarts` for p3.

When I click save I want those values to then save back to p3 so in the future when I load p3 it will have new updated values.

I can think of ways to do this but all seem extremely lengthy and inefficient.

Could anyone offer advise on the best way of doing this?

Comment: What is the way you're trying out currently to save the values when user clicks Save?

Comment: I have edited my main question to show the save()

Answer (score 0):

So to begin with I modified your save to save those players based on the `Player` itself instead of hardcoding in `p3` etc into the `String`s and made a helper method that saves a single `Player` named `savePlayer`.

```
public void save() {

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

savePlayer(editor, p3);
savePlayer(editor, p4);
savePlayer(editor, p5);

//OVERALL_HIGH_OUT is a class variable.
editor.putInt("highOut", OVERALL_HIGH_OUT);
editor.apply();
}

//Used to save a single Player based on the Player Object
public void savePlayer(SharedPreferences.Editor editor, Player p)
{
    editor.putInt(p.getName() + "TotalScore", p.getTotalScore());
    editor.putInt(p.getName() + "p4TotalDarts", p.getTotalDarts());
    editor.putInt(p.getName() + "p4HighOut", p.getHighout());
}
```

Now because the key in your `editor` is now based on the name stored into each `Player` object you can easily create a constructor for `Player` that creates an Object according to the `SharedPreferences` and `playerName` that loads the key based on the name:

```
public Player(SharedPreferences sharedPref, String playerName)
{
    this.name = playerName;
    this.totalScore = sharedPref.getInt(playerName + "TotalScore", -1); // -1 is default to set if preference does not exist
    this.totalDarts = sharedPref.getInt(playerName + "TotalDarts", -1);
    this.highOut = sharedPref.getInt(playerName + "HighOut", -1);
}
```

And here is how you might use that to create the same `Player` object from before based on the name you found to be the same:

```
Player p1 = new Player(); //Or however you start the declaration
if (p1Name.equals(p3.getName())) {
      p1 = new Player(sharedPref, p1Name);
}
```

`Player p1` will now have the same settings as that specific name if it was used before.  Although here is just specifically checking against whatever `p3` is.

**Note:**  Is is pretty simple to modify the constructor code to turn it into a method that returns a `Player` instead, if that fits your requirement better.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am very new to Java and Android but this seems to make sense, I will give it a try and see if I can work out how to use it. Thanks for your help.